# What's the difference between a watermark and a trigger in Flink?

Tags: stream, bigdata, real-time, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I read that, "..The ordering operator has to buffer all elements it receives. Then, when it receives a watermark it can sort all elements that have a timestamp that is lower than the watermark and emit them in the sorted order. This is correct because the watermark signals that not more elements can arrive that would be intermixed with the sorted elements..." - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/Time+and+Order+in+Streams

Hence, it seems that the watermark serves as a signal to the following operator, for beginning processing. I guess, that's what also a Trigger does. What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 5):

You can think of watermarks as special records that tell an operator what (event-) time it is. When an operator receives a watermark, it compares the watermark with its current time and other watermarks it received from different stream partitions. Depending on the comparison, the operator advances its own clock.

Some operators register timers (windows, time-based joins, custom implementations). An operator triggers a timer when the clock of the operator passes the time for which the timer was registered.

So, watermarks and timers are two different things. Watermarks tell an operator what time it is and the operator triggers a timer at the right point in time.

Comment: So, if I want an event-time based session window to be processed, say after 5 minutes, do I need to set an appropriate watermark function or an event-time based trigger?

Comment: You only need to generate watermarks (as for every other event-time application) and add an event-time session window with a gap time of five minutes to your data flow. You don't have to deal with timers at all. The window will automatically register and process timers as needed.

Comment: That would process the window when there is a gap of five minutes. So, the window might keep on registering events for say, 15 minutes and after a gap of 5 minutes, that is, after the 15 + 5 minutes, it will execute. Right? I would like it to not wait for the 15 minutes, but execute after the 5 first minutes, even if new events keep coming in.

Comment: OK, that exceeds the scope of this question. Session windows in Flink are triggered after a gap of inactivity. If you need a different behavior, I'd recommend to implement the logic with a `ProcessFunction`.

Comment: Ok. Just wanted to confirm if I could achieve this behavior through some watermarking function or event trigger. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

A Watermark can be thought of as an assertion that an event time stream is now complete up to a particular timestamp. When a Watermark is processed by an operator it will cause the firing of any relevant event time timers. The operators that use EventTimeTimers are EventTimeWindows and ProcessFunctions.

Triggers are part of the window API and define when Windows will produce results. An EventTimeTrigger wraps around an event time timer that is called when an suitably large Watermark is processed, indicating that the window is now complete.